# How to change color of a cell in one sheet if its value increases or decreases from another cell value in a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am putting together a workbook with 52 sheets for the weeks in the year. In this workbook there are multiple columns for percentages on each sheet.

I want to be able to change the color of each cell based on whethernit increases (green) or decreases (red) from the same cell in the previous sheet.

I have the formula i.e.  `=IF(ISERROR(B4/D4),"0", B4/D4)` to calculate my percentages but I don't know how to put the reference in for this change.  Any help?

Comment: I don't have access to Excel right now for a proper answer, but you should try searching Excel help and here for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If your percentages are week-on-week changes, then two rules for conditional formatting `=E1<1` with red and `=E1>1` with green might work (assuming your percentages are in ColumnE) but I'm not sure you describe your data in sufficient detail and 52 sheets looks excessive, as a single sheet might save duplication and unnecessary calculation.